# VMplayer doesn't show installed virtual machine

Tags: vmware

Last night I installed VMplayer and installed Windows XP professional but this morning its gone.
Please help where is that or how to start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not exactly an ubuntu question ..

VMWare Player on ubuntu seems not to remember the VMs from one session to the next one. So just "Open a VM" from the GUI.

Comment: yes, that's right.
I opened VMware player and browse for the saved machine and its working.
May be a difference between player and workstation.

Comment: But you can't edit the settings this way :/

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's right.
I opened VMware player and browse for the saved machine and its working.
May be a difference between player and workstation.